# I have to access the variables declared in java program from my c program using JNI in eclipse

Tags: java, c, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is my java code

```java
package com.example.javacallinc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class JNITest extends Activity {
static {
System.loadLibrary( "JNITest" );
}
private int i = 42;
public String s = "Written in Java";
public static double sd = 3.14;
//protected static String ss = "JNI - Java";
public native String modifyVariables();
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
super.onCreate(b);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
String s = modifyVariables();
s += "After calling C code, variables are:\n";
s += "i = " + Integer.toString(i) + "\n";
s += "s = " + s + "\n";
s += "sd = " + sd + "\n";
//s += "ss = " + ss + "\n";
tv.setText(s);
setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

This is my c code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<jni.h>


jstring
Java_org_linaro_jnitest_JNITest_modifyVariables(JNIEnv*env, jobject *o) {
jclass thisClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,o);
jfieldID id_i = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,thisClass, "i", "I");
jfieldID id_s = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,thisClass, "s", "Ljava/lang/String;");
jfieldID id_sd = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,thisClass, "sd", "D");
jfieldID id_ss = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,thisClass, "ss", "Ljava/lang/String;");
jint c_i = (*env)->GetIntField(env, thisClass, id_i);
jstring c_s = (jstring)(*env)->GetObjectField(env,thisClass, id_s);
jdouble c_sd = (*env)->GetStaticDoubleField(env,thisClass, id_sd);
jstring c_ss = (jstring)(*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, thisClass, id_ss);
char *cs_s = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, c_s, NULL);
char *cs_sd = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, c_sd,NULL);
char buf[512];
snprintf(buf, 512, "Variables initially seen by C code:\ni=%u\ns=%s\nsd=%f\nss=%s\n\n", c_i, cs_s, c_sd,cs_ss);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, c_s, cs_s);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, c_ss, cs_ss);
(*env)->SetIntField(env, thisClass, id_i, 1701);
(*env)->SetObjectField(env, thisClass, id_s,
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Written in C"));
(*env)->SetStaticDoubleField(env, thisClass,id_sd, 3.1415926);
(*env)->SetStaticObjectField(env, thisClass,id_ss, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "JNI - C"));
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

I am getting an error like this when i run the program in eclipse-

```
java.lang.unstaisfiedlinkerror:native library not included.
```

I have included the library in Android.mk also.
please help me...

Comment: Formatting your code so that it is readable would help

Answer (score 0):

In some way you are calling out a library that isn't present while you overlooked it. I don't understand all of the code but i recommend you to try and see if all the libraries that could be called upon by your code are imported.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your Android.mk file. Also make sure JNITest.so files are generated for all platforms specified in your application.mk(this does not exist by default, but you can create one and specify parameters like APP_ABI:=all which would mean , a .so file would be created for every platform). By default you should atleast see a arm folder created within your jni folder and it should contain the corresponding .so file.